# Як правильно вживати "ожеледь" чи "ожеледиця"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Допоможіть, будь ласка. Правильно говорити "ожеледь" чи "ожеледиця"?

Comment: У яких словниках Ви намагалися шукати ці слова самостійно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинка з сайту [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/ozheled-i-ozheleduczya)

[image]

> Мовознавці радять розрізняти:
>
> **Ожеледь** – кристали льоду або снігу, якими обростають стовбури й гілки
>   дерев, дроти тощо: вкриватися ожеледдю, слабка ожеледь уранці.
>
> **Ожеледиця** – тонкий шар льоду на поверхні землі: ожеледиця на дорогах,
>   братися ожеледицею.

Answer (score 0):

> ОЖЕЛЕ́ДИЦЯ, і, жін. Те саме, що ожеледь. Вона розіп'яла черкесовий
>   платок, розстебнула комір у ватянці і, прямуючи до волості, немов і не
>   помічала ні вітру, ні снігу, ні слизької ожеледиці (Любов Яновська, I,
>   1959, 343); Зранку сіялася дрібненька мжичка, але згодом випогодилося
>   і почалася ожеледиця (Антон Хижняк, Тамара, 1959, 197).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ozheledycja)

Answer (score 0):

- [moyaosvita.com.ua](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/tvarunu/chim-vidriznyayetsya-ozheled-vid-ozheledici/):

> **Ожеледь** – це нашарування льоду, які з’являються на землі, деревах, автомобілях та інших предметах внаслідок намерзання вологи. Це може
>   бути дощ, сніг, туман або просто холодне повітря. Фактично, це
>   атмосферні опади, які формують щільний шар льоду. Ожеледь з’являється
>   або при різкому зниженні температури до мінус 10 градусів Цельсія, або
>   при різкому підвищенні, коли предмети все одно залишаються холодними.
>
> **Ожеледиця** – це шар льоду, який з’являється на поверхні землі внаслідок замерзання рідкої субстанції (води або талого снігу). Він
>   формується при відносно невеликих мінусових температурах (до мінус 3
>   градусів Цельсія). Ожеледицею також називають накат снігу, що з’явився
>   в результаті механічних впливів автомобільних покришок або взуттєвих
>   підошов.

- К. В. Ленець "Ожеледь і ожеледиця" на [kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine13-14.pdf):

> Синоптики користуються термінами *ожеледь* і *ожеледиця*. У їхній професійній мові ці слова називають різні атмосферні явища, процес утворення яких не однаковий.
>
> В одному випадку `замерзають переохолоджені краплі` дрібного дощу або мряки при слабкому морозі. Дерева, будинки, земля вкриваються з навітряного боку шаром льоду. Це атмосферне явище синоптики називають *о́желеддю*.
>
> В іншому випадку `замерзає вода` на охолодженій поверхні землі, коли після
>   дощу або відлиги ударить мороз. Дороги вкриваються шаром льоду. Таке атмосферне явище у синоптиків називається *ожеле́дицею*.
>
> ... синоптики часто попереджають: **«Вранці місцями слабка ожеледь, на дорогах ожеледиця»**

Також

> Ожеледиця звичайно спостерігається тоді, коли є умови для ожеледі, обидва явища відбуваються одночасно і розрізняються тільки спеціалістами.

- [Один з уроків державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/22.htm) також розглядає це питання:

> На деревах ожеледь, на дорогах — ожеледиця.

---

Отже, різниця в значеннях є.